# Problems with building image using snap docker

Tags: linux, docker, linux-mint

This is my docker:

```
» which docker
/snap/bin/docker
» docker --version
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build a04f55b
```

Which I installed with:

```
sudo snap install docker
```

I try to build an image:

```
» docker build -f ./Dockerfile .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

The `Dockerfile` is there:

```
»  ls -l Dockerfile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 damane damane 144 Aug  8 13:48 Dockerfile
```

This is my system:

```
» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara
Release:        19
Codename:       tara
```

Comment: Try `docker build .` without setting the Dockerfile path

Comment: @juanlumn Already tried that (that was my initial command, and moved to the explicit version thinking that I could workaround the bug)

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?, also the Dockerfile is called Dockerfile and not Dockerfile.txt or something like that, right?

Comment: @juanlumn yes, no extension. I have found a workaround: install docker with `sudo apt install docker.io` instead of `sudo snap install docker`. It seems the snap packages are not well curated?

Comment: No idea... did it worked with `sudo apt install docker.io`?

Comment: @juanlumn yes, it did

Comment: This is [a packaging bug](https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/issues/34).

Answer (score 6):

This does not directly answer your problem with the snap installation but, I would recommend not using the snap, but following the instructions on the [docker documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

That way you'll always have the official and updated release

Comment: I can confirm on my end that after removing the snap and installing it through standard channels, this issue went away.  Therefore, this does indeed seem to directly answer the problem.